# Как превратить обычный рисунок в трёхмерный на ПК?

Tags: дизайн

Здравствуйте! Я отсканировал рисунок, а теперь мне его нужно превратить в 3d-изображение очень срочно. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это сделать. По возможности  опишите всю последовательность действий. И ещё: какую программу надо использовать? Точнее, какой графический редактор? Я начинающий программист, который решил создать флеш-игру, а художник к этому времени уже сдал работы. Как, а главное - с помощью какой программы можно вырезать рисунок, добавить 3D-эффект, как во всех современных видеоиграх, и наделить цветом? Буду премного благодарен за исчерпывающий ответ.

Comment: Надо нарисовать карту высот, сконвертировать ее в карту нормалей и отрендерить через бамп мап шейдер, либо наложить карту высот на полигональную сетку если вам нужен меш. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping

Comment: Берёте плоскую картинку и растягиваете её по высоте (руками). Графический редактор -- их много, посмотрите blender. http:://www.blender.org (Правда такие инструменты называются не графические редакторы, а несколько иначе)

Comment: Приведите свой скан, и чужую картинку, похожую на результат, который вам требуется. Может, можно без 3D обойтись, добавив теней и бликов?

Answer (score 4):

Никак, это задача для художника, а не для программиста.

Всю нужную графику должен предоставить художник.

Для того, чтобы сделать из двумерной картинки трёхмерную, у вас недостаточно данных. Художник может восполнить недостаток фантазией и чутьём, программист не обязан этого делать, и если он возьмётся, результат с точки зрения дизайна обычно получается отвратительным.

Представьте себе, что вам дали картинку 10x10 пикселей, и просят как-то обработать, чтобы на ней можно было разглядеть лица. Не кажется выполнимой задачей? Ваша задача из той же серии.

Пусть ваш работодатель потратит деньги и наймёт художника.

Comment: Ну, не 3D. Как вырезать аккуратно и добавить цвет?
Как мне известно, художники только делают наброски...

Comment: @prog: Это не дело программиста. Если хотите этим заняться, потребуйте себе вторую зарплату за художника. Вам придётся выучить граф. программы и развить в себе художественный вкус.

Comment: > Как мне известно, художники только делают наброски...

Художники разные бывают.

Comment: @prog, @Flammable: вот именно, надо нанять такого художника, который сделает не только наброски. Программисты же за него не дорисовывать не будут?

Comment: Действительно, в такой (как в вопросе) постановке задачи нужен художник.

А вообще, идея интересная. Распознавание образов, определение координат наблюдателя и источников света, масштабирование и т.д.

Comment: http://www.agisoft.ru/products
http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/

Вот еще два проекта известных. Но нужны все равно стереокартинки чтобы получить меш.